# Age Verification

Tags: php, jquery

I got stumped doing age verification and am wondering what's the best way now. It does not have to be robust, my initial plan was using jquery.

I found this resource, 
http://www.techerator.com/2010/09/how-to-perform-age-verification-with-jquery-and-cookies-mmm-cookies/

For ease of use, I have pasted the method here:

**Used on pages that need verification**

```
if ($.cookie('is_legal') == "yes") {
 //legal!
} else {
 document.location = "http://www.domain.com/[pathtofile]/verify.php?redirect=http://<?php echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>";
}
```

**The verification page**

```
$('#accept-btn').click(function(){
 $.cookie('is_legal', 'yes', { expires: 1, path: '/', domain: 'domain.com' });

 <?php if ( !isset($_REQUEST['redirect']) || $_REQUEST['redirect'] == "" ) { ?>
 document.location = "http://www.domain.com";

 <?php }else{ ?>
 document.location = "<?php echo $_REQUEST['redirect']; ?>";
 <?php } ?>
});
```

here is the html part of it.

```
<p>Are you OVER 18</p>
<div id="accept-btn">YES</div>
<div id="noaccept-btn">     NO</div >
```

First issue is that the else statement is not working, as well it seems to be using the same variable for the redirect for the YES option and the NO option.

SO I am curious, just for learning sake, why this is not working properly and how to fix, and secondly what's really the better way here. Like I said seo/php or a robust way is not critical.

My desired result is that, when they access any page on the site they get a yes or no option and then, when YES they get access to the page, if they choose no, it's a redirect.

Comment: I guess you'd have to be eighteen years old to figure out how to set a cookie in the browser using JavaScript, right?

Comment: You are mixing languages in a single statement. Short answer is don't do that. Ever.

Comment: Tadman, you might find this useful, it's got pictures too http://www.wikihow.com/Be-Sarcastic

Comment: Fresheye, ok, gotcha, I found that tutorial online and it was not working right.

Comment: @Deedub the tutorial does not mix languages. No one mixes languages, because its a very bad idea. Also you have not provided enough information to debug this. Please provide the code for the `NO` option, as well as the html for the the buttons. Also please be more clear as to your desired result. What is the difference between `http://www.domain.com` and `<?php echo $_REQUEST['redirect']; ?>` for example.

Comment: To understand why this is wrong you need to understand the client-server model first. PHP is interpreted **before** JavaScript. You can generate JS in PHP but it's all text, they don't understand each other, you need a format to transfer your data from and to the server, like JSON or XML. But the nature of the web is synchronous, you'd have to leave to page to send or receive info, that's when AJAX comes in, it lets you do it asynchronously, without a page refresh.

Comment: Don't forget Tadman's right-hand man ;-) "moi" And George C., God rest his comedy soul. There's a certain thing about Canadian comedy, a *"je ne sais quoi"* type of thing ;-) Wouldn't you say @tadman ? ;-)

Comment: Fresheye - thanks! I guess I am confused alittle. There was no real clear explanation of what the NO button was. I assumed that it was implemented in the ELSE part.

Comment: elclanrs - gothca - thanks!

Comment: Fred - here is a resource for you.  http://www.wikihow.com/Be-Funny

Comment: did you add jquery and jquery.cookie.js?

Comment: yeah, :) Not that far back, ha.

Comment: @Deedub [**Here**](http://www.georgecarlin.com/) <= he'll set you straight, and you can [**subscribe to this channel**](http://www.thecomedynetwork.ca/) - Enjoy the ride ;-)

Answer (score 3):

How about a pure PHP version of this??

```
<?php

/**
 * @author - Sephedo
 * @for - Deedub @ Stackoverflow
 * @question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751788/age-verification
 */

$min_age = 18; // Set the min age in years

if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
{
    if( mktime(0, 0, 0, $_POST['month'], $_POST['day'], $_POST['year'] ) < mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('j'), ( date('Y') - $min_age ) ) )
    {
        var_dump("over $min_age");
    }
    else
    {
        var_dump("under $min_age");
    }
}

?>

<form method="POST" >
<fieldset>
<legend>Enter your age</legend>
<label for="day" >Day:</label>
<select name="day" >
<?php
    for( $x=1; $x <= 31; $x++ )
    {
        if( $x == date("j" ) ) echo "<option selected>$x</option>"; else echo "<option>$x</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
<label for="day" >Month:</label>
<select name="month" >
<?php
    for( $x=1; $x<=12; $x++ )
    {
        if( $x == date("m" ) ) echo "<option selected>$x</option>"; else echo "<option>$x</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
<label for="day" >Year:</label>
<select name="year" >
<?php
    for( $x=date("Y"); $x>=(date("Y")-100); $x-- )
    {
        echo "<option>$x</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: sephendo, that could work too! THANK YOU!  I think it would be simpler to have a simple yes or no.

Comment: I have added another answer with just the yes and no buttons

Comment: I also added the cookie bit - be careful when testing and add setcookie('age_verification', '') at the top to reset

Answer (score 0):

New Version as requested in comments

```
<?php
    /**
     * @author - Sephedo
     * @for - Deedub @ Stackoverflow
     * @question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751788/age-verification
     */

    // ADD TO ALL PAGES WHICH NEED TO HAVE AGE VERIFICATION
    session_start();
    if(! isset( $_SESSION['age_verification'] ) or $_SESSION['age_verification'] != true ) die( header("Location: checkage.php?url=http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]") );

    // session_destroy(); // uncomment to reset for testing and debugging.

    echo 'hello over 18 person';

?>

<?php

    /**
     * @author - Sephedo
     * @for - Deedub @ Stackoverflow
     * @question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751788/age-verification
     */

    // checkage.php
    session_start();

    // checkage.php
    if( isset( $_POST['yes'] ) )
    {
        $_SESSION['age_verification'] = true;

        if( isset( $_GET['url'] ) )
        {
            die( header('Location: ' . $_GET['url'] ) ); 
        } 
        else
        {
            die( header('Location: index.php') );
        }
    }
    elseif( isset( $_POST['no'] ) )
    {
        $_SESSION['age_verification'] = false;
    }

    // The below line will check if someone has already said no so you can show them a page which tells them to they are too young.
    if( isset( $_SESSION['age_verification'] ) and $_SESSION['age_verification'] != true ) die( header('Location: tooyoung.php') );

    ?>

    <form method="POST" >
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Are you over 18?</legend>
    <input type="submit" name="yes" value="Yes" /> <input type="submit" name="no" value="No" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: thanks Sephedo- so how does it capture the url of the specific page you are on, assuming people can visit any page on the site?

Comment: so you are redirecting back.. ill add something in.

Comment: I have changed the above answer what do you think? tried and tested code

Comment: I get the yes or not abouve the page content and it still shows the page... weird :)

Comment: I did make a tweek just after posting it just try copying it again see if that makes a difference

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I just tried it again, and it still hows the page.