# PHP age check - Intercept and redirect

Tags: php, redirect

I am developing a website which involves some information about alcohol, and the client has requested an age check for access to this page. I know how utterly useless they are but I assume there are some regulations in place for this.

After some research I found that PHP is the better way to do an age check, since disabling javascript would render a check based on JS useless. However my PHP knowledge is not great. I found an answer here which pointed me in the right direction: [Age Verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751788/age-verification)

Problem is now, it's not working correctly.

The process works as follows:

- User accesses brands.php page. PHP checks for age verification session data, and redirects to checkage.php if the check has not been done already:

  ```
  <?php 
  include_once("includes/header.php");

  session_start();

  if(!isset( $_SESSION['age_verification'] ) or $_SESSION['age_verification'] != true )   die( header("Location: checkage.php?url=http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]") );

  //session_destroy(); // uncomment to reset for testing and debugging.

  echo 'hello over 18 person';

  ?>
  ```
- checkage.php contains the form for checking the age (unpredictably). I combined the author's two answers on that thread to make what I thought should work. I placed an if statement to get the url of the brands page and redirect there if the age is right, and a redirect to the home page otherwise. The code for that page is as follows:

  ```
  <?php

  $min_age = 18; // Set the min age in years

  if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
  {
  $_SESSION['age_verification'] = true;

      if( mktime(0, 0, 0, $_POST['month'], $_POST['day'], $_POST['year'] ) < mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('j'), ( date('Y') - $min_age ) ) )
      {
          if( isset( $_GET['url'] ) )
          {
              header('Location: ' . $_GET['url'] ); 
          } 
      }
      else
      {
          header('Location: index.php');
      }
  }
  else 
  {
  $_SESSION['age_verification'] = false;
  }

  // The below line will check if someone has already said no so you can show them a page which tells them to they are too young.
  //if( isset( $_SESSION['age_verification'] ) and $_SESSION['age_verification'] != true ) die( header('Location: tooyoung.php') );

  ?>

  <form method="POST" >
      <fieldset>
          <legend>Enter your age</legend>
          <label for="day" >Day:</label>
          <select name="day" >
          <?php
          for( $x=1; $x <= 31; $x++ )
          {
              if( $x == date("j" ) ) echo "<option selected>$x</option>"; else echo "  <option>$x</option>";
          }
          ?>
          </select>

          <label for="day" >Month:</label>
          <select name="month" >
          <?php
          for( $x=1; $x<=12; $x++ )
          {
          if( $x == date("m" ) ) echo "<option selected>$x</option>"; else echo "<option>$x</option>";
          }
          ?>
          </select>

          <label for="day" >Year:</label>
          <select name="year" >
          <?php
          for( $x=date("Y"); $x>=(date("Y")-100); $x-- )
          {
              echo "<option>$x</option>";
          } 
          ?>
          </select>

          <input type="submit" name="submit" />
      </fieldset>
  </form>
  ```

This process does exactly what I want to happen: intercept the user trying to access the page > redirect to age check > go to page or back to home depending on input. I just don't know what's wrong with it.

Sorry for the long question, trying to be as clear as possible. Any help is really appreciated! Although I expect I'm doing something incredibly obvious and stupid...

Comment: checkage.php also need session_start(); i did not see this line. did you just miss it? you can use var_dump($_SESSION) to dump session value to check if you had set the variable correctly

Comment: Well. That was spectacularly simple. Nothing more than human error on my part. Thank you for making my day a good deal less painful!

Comment: You mean you miss the session_start() or you solve this by using var_dump?

Comment: Sorry, I was missing session_start() from checkage.php!

Comment: ok,then check my answer as solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed session_start()

```
<?php
session_start();
//you missed above line!
$min_age = 18; // Set the min age in years

if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
{
$_SESSION['age_verification'] = true;

    if( mktime(0, 0, 0, $_POST['month'], $_POST['day'], $_POST['year'] ) < mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('j'), ( date('Y') - $min_age ) ) )
    {
        if( isset( $_GET['url'] ) )
        {
            header('Location: ' . $_GET['url'] ); 
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I would have checked the answer right away except you posted it in a comment :)

Comment: I have session_start() on my contact page and form process page. This seems to be resetting the session for the checkage page also, meaning anytime you go the contact page and back to the brands page (which is were the checkage happens) the session is restarted there too. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Scratch that, I used session_write_close(); instead of session_destroy(); at the end of the contact page and now all seems to be working.