# Age veryfication php redirecting

Tags: php

I have code from the stack question [Age Verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751788/age-verification) - I have changed the header location to redirect to google.com

```
     <?php

        /**
         * @author - Sephedo
         * @for - Deedub @ Stackoverflow
         * @question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751788/age-verification
         */

        // checkage.php
        session_start();

        // checkage.php
        if( isset( $_POST['yes'] ) )
        {
            $_SESSION['age_verification'] = true;

            if( isset( $_GET['url'] ) )
            {
                die( header('Location: ' . $_GET['url'] ) ); 
            } 
            else
            {
                die( header('Location: index.php') );
            }
        }
        elseif( isset( $_POST['no'] ) )
        {
            $_SESSION['age_verification'] = false;
        }

        // The below line will check if someone has already said no so you can show them a page which tells them to they are too young.
        if( isset( $_SESSION['age_verification'] ) and $_SESSION['age_verification'] != true ) die( header('Location: http://google.com') );

        ?>
<form method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <legend class="age-question">Are you 18?/legend>
                <input id="yes" type="submit" name="yes" />
                <input id="no" type="submit" name="no" />
            </fieldset>
</form>
```

On my page are two buttons to choose from if you are 18 or older. When I click the 'No' button, the server redirects me to Google. But clicking 'Yes' redirects to Google as well, instead of going to my page and verifying the age as indented.

How can I fix this so the verification will display again if I click 'No' after redirecting, then go to my website?

Comment: Looks like that was done on purpose by design - so that (rather unknowledgable) users (who don't know how to clear their cookies) wouldn't be able to go back to the website and _lie_ to get past the age check.

Comment: becuse its so hard to lie the first time around :-)

Comment: @Dagon That's why they're rather unknowledgable haha

Comment: @Robson, please clarify what you're asking. Are you saying that even if someone previously answered "No", you want them to come back to the site and be able to answer "Yes"?

Comment: @sjagr - what if many people use the same pc ? It's good way for porn sites etc. I have site with alcohol products and law in my coutry order me to do that :(

Comment: @JonathanM I want to have exactly this result.

Answer (score 1):

Its because the session is never destroyed, this line
`if( isset( $_SESSION['age_verification'] ) and $_SESSION['age_verification'] != true )` returns true as the session variable `age_verification` is intact and has a value `false` if you previously selected `NO` as an option.