# PHP Age Verification

Tags: php

I'm trying to verify if a visitor to a site is of legal age or under 18.

I'm trying to work off of an answer given at [Age Verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751788/age-verification)

I'm using the following part from that question/answer:

```
/**
 * @author - Sephedo
 * @for - Deedub @ Stackoverflow
 * @question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751788/age-verification
 */
$min_age = 18;

if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
{
    if( mktime(0, 0, 0, $_POST['month'], $_POST['day'], $_POST['year'] ) < mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), date('j'), ( date('Y') - $min_age ) ) )
    {
        echo("over $min_age");
    }
    else
    {
        echo("under $min_age");
    }
}
```

And then my form is:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
<fieldset>

<?php
    // lowest year wanted
    $cutoff = 1910;

    // current year
    $now = date('Y');

    // build months menu
    echo '<div class="form-group">' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Month</label>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<div class="col-md-4">' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<select name="month" class="form-control">' . PHP_EOL;
    for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {
        echo '  <option value="' . $m . '">' . date('F', mktime(0,0,0,$m)) . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</select>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;

    // build days menu
    echo '<div class="form-group">' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Day</label>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<div class="col-md-4">' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<select name="day" class="form-control">' . PHP_EOL;
    for ($d=1; $d<=31; $d++) {
        echo '  <option value="' . $d . '">' . $d . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</select>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;

    // build years menu
    echo '<div class="form-group">' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Year</label>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<div class="col-md-4">' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<select name="year" class="form-control">' . PHP_EOL;
    for ($y=$now; $y>=$cutoff; $y--) {
        echo '  <option value="' . $y . '">' . $y . '</option>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</select>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
?>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton">Done?</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

When I submit the form there is no new output on the page from `echo("over $min_age");` or `echo("under $min_age");`.

Am I overlooking something?

Just to save time here is the HTML output of my form without the PHP:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/landing.php">
<fieldset>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Month</label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<select name="month" class="form-control">
  <option value="1">January</option>
  <option value="2">February</option>
  <option value="3">March</option>
  <option value="4">April</option>
  <option value="5">May</option>
  <option value="6">June</option>
  <option value="7">July</option>
  <option value="8">August</option>
  <option value="9">September</option>
  <option value="10">October</option>
  <option value="11">November</option>
  <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Day</label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<select name="day" class="form-control">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="26">26</option>
  <option value="27">27</option>
  <option value="28">28</option>
  <option value="29">29</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">Year</label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<select name="year" class="form-control">
  <option value="2016">2016</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
  <option value="2014">2014</option>
  <option value="2013">2013</option>
  <option value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2011">2011</option>
  <option value="2010">2010</option>
  <option value="2009">2009</option>
  <option value="2008">2008</option>
  <option value="2007">2007</option>
  <option value="2006">2006</option>
  <option value="2005">2005</option>
  <option value="2004">2004</option>
  <option value="2003">2003</option>
  <option value="2002">2002</option>
  <option value="2001">2001</option>
  <option value="2000">2000</option>
  <option value="1999">1999</option>
  <option value="1998">1998</option>
  <option value="1997">1997</option>
  <option value="1996">1996</option>
  <option value="1995">1995</option>
  <option value="1994">1994</option>
  <option value="1993">1993</option>
  <option value="1992">1992</option>
  <option value="1991">1991</option>
  <option value="1990">1990</option>
  <option value="1989">1989</option>
  <option value="1988">1988</option>
  <option value="1987">1987</option>
  <option value="1986">1986</option>
  <option value="1985">1985</option>
  <option value="1984">1984</option>
  <option value="1983">1983</option>
  <option value="1982">1982</option>
  <option value="1981">1981</option>
  <option value="1980">1980</option>
  <option value="1979">1979</option>
  <option value="1978">1978</option>
  <option value="1977">1977</option>
  <option value="1976">1976</option>
  <option value="1975">1975</option>
  <option value="1974">1974</option>
  <option value="1973">1973</option>
  <option value="1972">1972</option>
  <option value="1971">1971</option>
  <option value="1970">1970</option>
  <option value="1969">1969</option>
  <option value="1968">1968</option>
  <option value="1967">1967</option>
  <option value="1966">1966</option>
  <option value="1965">1965</option>
  <option value="1964">1964</option>
  <option value="1963">1963</option>
  <option value="1962">1962</option>
  <option value="1961">1961</option>
  <option value="1960">1960</option>
  <option value="1959">1959</option>
  <option value="1958">1958</option>
  <option value="1957">1957</option>
  <option value="1956">1956</option>
  <option value="1955">1955</option>
  <option value="1954">1954</option>
  <option value="1953">1953</option>
  <option value="1952">1952</option>
  <option value="1951">1951</option>
  <option value="1950">1950</option>
  <option value="1949">1949</option>
  <option value="1948">1948</option>
  <option value="1947">1947</option>
  <option value="1946">1946</option>
  <option value="1945">1945</option>
  <option value="1944">1944</option>
  <option value="1943">1943</option>
  <option value="1942">1942</option>
  <option value="1941">1941</option>
  <option value="1940">1940</option>
  <option value="1939">1939</option>
  <option value="1938">1938</option>
  <option value="1937">1937</option>
  <option value="1936">1936</option>
  <option value="1935">1935</option>
  <option value="1934">1934</option>
  <option value="1933">1933</option>
  <option value="1932">1932</option>
  <option value="1931">1931</option>
  <option value="1930">1930</option>
  <option value="1929">1929</option>
  <option value="1928">1928</option>
  <option value="1927">1927</option>
  <option value="1926">1926</option>
  <option value="1925">1925</option>
  <option value="1924">1924</option>
  <option value="1923">1923</option>
  <option value="1922">1922</option>
  <option value="1921">1921</option>
  <option value="1920">1920</option>
  <option value="1919">1919</option>
  <option value="1918">1918</option>
  <option value="1917">1917</option>
  <option value="1916">1916</option>
  <option value="1915">1915</option>
  <option value="1914">1914</option>
  <option value="1913">1913</option>
  <option value="1912">1912</option>
  <option value="1911">1911</option>
  <option value="1910">1910</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton">Done?</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking is "submit" set in POST but you don't have any inputs with that name, so it will be never set. Try to add name on your submit button:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Of course. Something so simple. I'll accept as soon as I can. Thanks. :)